# Linq request with BETWEEN

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm trying to do a `Linq` request with two wheres, the problem is the syntax for the Between request.
`TransactionDateTime` has this format `"YYYY-MM-DD 12:48:19 252"`
My variables : `strBeginnAbfr` `"2019-01-01"`, `strEndeAbfr` `"2019-01-31"`

I already tried another syntax I've found online, but it also didn't work.

```
 var abfrageGpNr = from x in db.Transactions
                                  where (x.GPNummer == strGPNrVar &&

                                   x.TransactionDateTime BETWEEN  strBeginnAbfr
                                 AND strEndeAbfr
                                 orderby x.TransactionDateTime 
                                  select x;
```

The result should be a list with Transactions with `GPNr` (1 user) and time horizon 1 month.

Comment: Is TransactionDateTime a string?

Comment: Parse the `TransactionDateTime` string using `DateTime.ParseExact(TransactionDateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` and use the parsed value in one of the provided answers below.

Comment: TransactionDateTime is a Column from database, with the following format "YYYY-MM-DD I tried the answers but it didn't helped.

Comment: @Cryptogear, I assume TransactionDateTime is a string. Are you variables strings? Try my answer below.

Comment: Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` script for the table you are querying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime) the strings to [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8) objects to compare them, which you do using standard [comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.op_lessthanorequal?view=netframework-4.8) operators. Also observe how the `let` keyword is used:

```
var beginDate = DateTime.ParseExact(strBeginnAbfr, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(strEndeAbfr, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var abfrageGpNr = from x in db.Transactions
                  let TxDate = x.TransactionDateTime 
                  where (x.GPNummer == strGPNrVar &&  
                  TxDate >= beginDate && TxDate <= endDate)
                  orderby TxDate 
                  select x;
```

Comment: Yes thanks a lot, this works for me. I don't need to parse TransactionsDateTime because its already from type datetime.

Comment: @Cryptogear, You're welcome. Now you can upvote as well. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var abfrageGpNr = from x in db.Transactions
                                  where (x.GPNummer == strGPNrVar &&   
                                   x.TransactionDateTime >= strBeginnAbfr
                                 AND x.TransactionDateTime <= strEndeAbfr)
                                 orderby x.TransactionDateTime 
                                  select x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use >= and <= to do comparison.

```
var abfrageGpNr = from x in db.Transactions
                where (x.GPNummer == strGPNrVar 
                && (x.TransactionDateTime >=  strBeginnAbfr && x.TransactionDateTime <= strEndeAbfr)
                orderby x.TransactionDateTime 
                select x;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no keyword `between` in LINQ,

Instead of this you need to do this in traditional way using `>=` and `<=`.

```
   var abfrageGpNr = from x in db.Transactions where (x.GPNummer == strGPNrVar 
            && (x.TransactionDateTime >=  strBeginnAbfr && x.TransactionDateTime <= strEndeAbfr) 
            orderby x.TransactionDateTime select x;
```